# Changing contents of a file through shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a requirement where in I need to change the contents of a file say xyz.cfg. the file contains values like:

```
group address=127.8.8.8
port=7845
Jboss username=xyz_ITR3
```

I want to change this content when ever needed through a shell script and save the file. Changed content can look like:

```
group address=127.8.7.7  
port=7822
Jboss username=xyz_ITR4
```

How can i achieve this using shell script by taking user input or otherwise?

Comment: You should ask a specific question for a particular problem. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."*

Answer (score 41, accepted):

How about something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

addr=$1
port=$2
user=$3

sed -i -e "s/\(address=\).*/\1$1/" \
-e "s/\(port=\).*/\1$2/" \
-e "s/\(username=\).*/\1$3/" xyz.cfg
```

Where `$1,$2` and `$3` are the arguments passed to the script. Save it a file such as `script.sh` and make sure it executable with `chmod +x script.sh` then you can run it like:

```
$ ./script.sh 127.8.7.7 7822 xyz_ITR4

$ cat xyz.cfg
group address=127.8.7.7
port=7822
Jboss username=xyz_ITR4
```

This gives you the basic structure however you would want to think about validating input ect.

Answer (score 22):

*

```
#! /bin/sh
file=xyz.cfg
addr=$1
port=$2
username=$3
sed -i 's/address=.*/address='$addr'/' $file
sed -i 's/port=.*/port='$port'/' $file
sed -i 's/username=.*/username='$username'/' $file
```

*

I hope this one will be simpler to understand for beginners

Comment: Thanks for this, never used sed before and had no idea what was going on in the accepted answer

Answer (score 10):

```
sed -i 's/something/other/g' filename.txt
```

Will edit filename.txt in-place, and change the word 'something' to 'other'

I think -i may be a GNU extension though, but if it's OK for you, you can add it via find, xargs etc.

If you would like to change it in a shell script, you can take arguments on the command-line and refer to them by number, eg $1

Edit:

As per my comment, sudo_O's answer below is exactly the example that you want. What I will add is that it's common that you'll want to do such matches with multiple files, spanning subdirectories etc, so get to know find/xargs, and you can combine the two. A simple example of say changing the subnet in a bunch of .cfg files could be:

```
find -name '*.cfg' -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} sed -ie 's/\(192.168\)\.1/\1\.7/' {}
```

Note the -print0/-0 args to find/xargs (very useful for paths/filenames with spaces), and that you have to escape the capturing brackets because of the shell (same in sudo's example)

Comment: >along with the other lines i have few more lines which will remain constant in the new file. So how to i put this new content along with old one?

Comment: I was about to add an example along the lines of sudo_O's, but his answer is the go; matching/capturing the "keys" you care about, and leaving the others unchanged

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the solutions above, you should watch out for the escape characters in the text you replacing.

For example, if you replacing something like `/home/user/` then you will not get the result that you would like to get.

To solve this problem you can change the delimiter from `/` to `|`. See the code sample below.

```
OLD="path/to/replace"
NEW="new/path"
file=file-to-search.log

sed "s|$OLD|$NEW|g" $file
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -i "s/$name/$new_name/g" address.txt
```

This command can also be used for modifying the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this as follows -

File **script.sh** :

```
while [ $# -gt 0 ]
do
 case "$1" in
     --group-address)
            export NEW_VAL1=$2
            shift 2
            ;;
     --port)
            export NEW_VAL2=$2
            shift 2
            ;;
     --username)
            export NEW_VAL3=$2
            shift 2
            ;;

    *)
    echo "Unrecognized option: $1"
    usage 1
    esac
done


sed -i 's/group address=.*/group address='$NEW_VAL1'/g' xyz.cfg
sed -i 's/port=.*/port=.'$NEW_VAL2'/g' xyz.cfg
sed -i 's/Jboss username=.*/Jboss username='$NEW_VAL3'/g' xyz.cfg
```

You can now update these values by passing respective arguments -

- --group-address
- --port
- --username

on command line to this script

For example -

```
./script.sh --group-address 127.8.7.7 --port  7822 --username xyz_ITR4
```