# Shell (tcsh) command to change the value corresponding to a key

Tags: shell, scripting, tcsh

What should be the Shell (tcsh) command if i want to change the value corresponding to the key in a properties file. For Example: Key=Value to Key=SomeOtherValue

Comment: what shell are you using?

Answer (score 2):

In tcsh (or csh, for that matter), you use the setenv command to write a value to an environment variable.

```
setenv Key SomeOtherValue
```

For more information take a look at any csh reference (because it's more widely used, and tcsh is completely compatible.)

For example, see [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/tcsh-csh-c_shell-set-variable-command/).

---

Update: OP has now clarified the the wants to edit the content of a properties file, not an environment variable.

Here is a good SO question/answer that solves this different problem nicely. It uses bash, but translating should be easy.

[Changing contents of a file through shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14643531/changing-contents-of-a-file-through-shell-script)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response @jwismar but Its not an environment variable, its a properties file where i want to change a value corresponding to a key via shell command.

Comment: Well, that changes things!